# Numerical Range of a principal submatrix is contained in the numerical range of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have found several papers from the 70s, stating a "well known" fact without proof:

The numerical range of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is given by $W(A) = \{ \langle Ax, x \rangle : \|x\| = 1 \}$.

A principal submatrix $A_{i}$ is created by striking out the $i$th column and $i$th row of the matrix.

The "well known" fact is that $W(A_i) \subseteq W(A)$. What is the proof?

Thanks,

Derek

Answer (score 3):

If $x'$ is obtained from $x \in \mathbb R^{n-1}$ by inserting a $0$ in position $i$, then $\|x'\| = \|x\|$ and $\langle x', A x' \rangle = \langle x, A_i x \rangle$.

Comment: Derp. Thank you!